# Can I speed up callbacks from C++ Dll to C#?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, callback

We've implemented our main code functionality in a C++ Dll then written a C# UI on top. This works fine most of the time, but in areas where we want the UI to report the progress of a function in C++ we're having some performance problems.

We pass a pointer to a C# function down to the Dll to use for progress updates. When it's called we use InvokeRequired and Invoke() to make sure the callback is thread-safe. Measured from the C++ side, this can take anything between 16ms and 180ms. Is there any way of reducing the time this takes?

One of these callbacks passes the location of a line to be drawn on the screen. This drawing currently very slow - I assume the invoked functions are queuing up and taking time to be drawn in C#. I can see two ways of dealing with this:
1. Change the callback to send a list of lines and allow the lines to queue up in C++ whilst waiting for the previous call to C# to complete.
2. Adding the lines to a queue in C# (preferably without calling Invoke) then drawing all lines that are available at once.
Any suggestions on how to do this, whether both options are required, or alternative methods?

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Not too sure about the best way to do this, but I can say that the managed-to-unmanaged transitions (and back) are definitely nonnegligible when they add up.

Comment: Have you considered the other way around as well: Have the new coordinates ready in C++ and fetch the current coordinates from C# via a timer? That way you would give the visual experience preceedance over the (may too many) number of data actually created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke`. `Invoke` waits for the function to return, while `BeginInvoke` allows the function to run parallel to the current thread.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the callback but likelys the invoke. Invoke is a potentially expensive operation. If you ahve a thread change there, it WILL take time. A lot. You alsoa re putting the drawing operations into the same thread, so the callback will block until those are finished.

What you can do:

- BeginInvoke - basically the callback erturns early, another thread does the drawing.
- Reduce the number of invokes, basically batching your requests. This can be done OUTSIDE The C++ dll - have the callback put the corodinates into a queue, then the queue in a separate thread call BeginInvoke.

Basically, your single threaded UI and the requirement of thread switching via dispatcher kill you, totally within the C# area.

At the end, your question is badly worded. C++ & C# has nothing to do with the problem, you would have the same issue with C# only. You have an API making callbacks into the UI that needs to switch threads (Invoke) and do UI operations, and this leads yo t he callback taking more time than you want. Replace C## with Smalltalk, Assembler, C#, Visual basic and the problem stays 100% the same.

Comment: It is not offends - it is just inaccurate. You simply did not try to nail down your problem enough.

Comment: I disagree - the first question is related to my C++ callback because I didn't understand why it took so long. I now appreciate the difference between Invoke() and BeginInvoke() and the C++ is running smoothly.

I don't understand your second suggestion - "This can be done OUTSIDE The C++ dll - have the callback put the corodinates into a queue, then the queue in a separate thread call BeginInvoke". If my callback only includes one line then what's the point of putting it on a queue in a thread? Do you mean the thread should be running permanently and drawing lines as they're provided?

Comment: Well, you did obviously not measure your performance problem. Get a profiler. THe second approach is wHt ai do often. I use async queues that then spawn a thread. You queue items, the queue starts a worker thread that would then invoke (itself) into the UI and pull items from the queue as needed. Every x items, or when empty, the thread would deinvoke back, so the UI can refresh. This allows me to handle thigns totally async withou tons of begin invoke calls, which in themselves are slow too (you just hide it at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, there is only *one* line, which should be drawn. But its coordinates are frequently generated in the unmanaged part and sent to C# to update the graphical representation? Consider enabling the drawing method to cancel itself. So when - while drawing a line - new coordinates arrive, discard the current line and just draw the new coordinates. That way you may get rid of the need to implement any queueing at all.

@Edit: I tend to the suggestion to better query all necessary data from the C++ part by C#. It sounds like you are calling back to .NET very often in order to control some visual output. But this should be done from .NET (which knows much better, how often it is possible at all). So, querying all data from C++ in a user defined structure may help.

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer. The callback is called multiple times, and many lines are drawn to the display.

Comment: @parsley72 I see. But my suggestion still holds - even more than. The UI part may fetch all data necessary for drawing in a constant interval from the C++ part. The transition would only be done once for each interval. And it is the responsibility of the UI to trigger the retrieval.